# Is it possibile to manually wire a displayport cable?

Tags: wire

I have to pass such a cable trought a small hole in a wall.
Since that the connector is to big to pass trough, the only way to do so is to cut the cable, pass it and than wire it manually.

Do I have any hope to do it successfully with a small loss of the cable quality?

Any suggestion on how to proceed?

I could always make another bigger hole in the wall, but I prefer to wire the cable, if that was possible.

Comment: Would a mini displayport connector fit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't say for certain that it's **impossible**, but at the very least it would be very very difficult to wire by hand.  Modern video cables like HDMI and displayport need high quality connections and wire, and I doubt you would be able to get the quality needed by hand.

The nice thing about digital video cables is that you'll know if it works - it either works, or doesn't work (or sometimes works in which case you'll either see nothing or a scrambled display).  There's should be no loss of picture quality.

So you can try it...but I have a feeling enlarging the hole would be your best bet.  Displayport connectors are still fairly small so the hole won't be too big.  Or you can do it the right way with a big hole and a faceplate.  You can get faceplates that just have a hole in the center to pass a wire through but are actually two pieces that snap together so you don't have to remove the connector.

Comment: Strangely enough I've actually once had an HDMI cable of dubious quality that actually produces a banding effect over the image it delivered. So yeah...depends on the encoding on the cable, but cable quality CAN affect image quality in a non-binary sense.

Comment: Indeed it can. The "all or nothing cliff" isn't so much a feature of digital systems in general as it is a feature of digital systems with compression algorithms combined with error checking and correction.

Comment: Well...there is still a cliff without FEC, it's just not as steep and you can get quite a bit more signal degredation before you get there.  If the signal is so bad the clock recovery circuiry can't lock reliably, you get nada.  And it can actually be dependent on the image shown on the display...i.e. with one image, you get digital snow but it shows up, however changing to a different image, perhaps generating a high transition density after the line code, causes the link to lose lock and the display to go blank.

Comment: I saw that happen at a dentist's office where somebody installed cheap HDMI to CAT-5 "converters" instead of running an HDMI cable the whole way.  The fix was to scrap the converters and replace the CAT-5 with a long HDMI cable.